# How to add watermark in sencha touch or ext js textfield

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I want to add a watermark text to sencha touch or ext js textbox similar to this: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/watermark.jsf

Any help or suggestions pls.
I am using Sencha Touch 2.3.1

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.field.Input-cfg-placeHolder

Comment: The link posted by Evan really helped. Thnx

Answer (score 2):

`.placeHolder` for Touch, `.emptyText` for ExtJs